# URL to use for Authorised redirect URLs

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

What is the URL to use for Authorised redirect URLs in Google's OAuth2 API? I've tried many variations, but they all come back with: `Error: redirect_uri_mismatch`.

The error mentions the following URL not configured:

> https://myowndomain.com/myapp/hybrid-auth/endpoint?hauth.done=Google

In the API console, I have configured these URLs at one point:

- https://myowndomain.com/myapp/hybrid-auth/endpoint
- https://myowndomain.com/myapp/hybrid-auth

Do I have to configure the whole URL, even the querystring? Or, perhaps this is a result of my website not accepting what Google is sending?

**Edit #1**

I get further now that I added the entire URL:
https://myowndomain.com/myapp/hybrid-auth/endpoint?hauth.done=Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configured redirect URL and the requested redirect URL must be a character-for-character match. I've never seen a URL with a query string before. Maybe it works, or maybe that's the problem. If you need to pass state through the dance, look at the `state=` parameter.

Comment: I've yet to try with the querystring, I guess I'll try that.